# Webpack очень долго собирает

Tags: javascript, webpack, loader

Написал конфигурацию для Webpack 3. Все работает, но есть одна большая проблема. Когда в проекте более 10 html страниц, сборщик очень долго собирает даже на dev конфигурации. Во время анализа сборки оказалось что при изменении любого файла (scss, pug или js) пересобираются полностью все файлы и страницы и каждый раз отрабатывают все лоадеры (file-loader, sprite-loader и тд) Подскажите как можно следить за измененным файлом и собирать только его?

Answer (score 1):

может вы включили минимизацию для dev?? (webpack4)

```
optimization: {
    minimize: true,



optimization: {
    //minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: false,
                ecma: 6,
                mangle: true
            },
            extractComments: false,
            sourceMap: true
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
},
```